# How to get the post_name when in preview?

Tags: functions, javascript

I'm using the below code in my `functions.php` file to include some JS only in posts I want. The code works fine for published posts and I can target a specific post, but how do I do it for posts that are not yet published, like viewing a draft post?

```
global $post;

if( is_page() || is_single() )
{
   switch($post->post_name)
    {
        case 'post-name-here':
        wp_register_script( 'charts', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js", array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('charts');
```

Comment: What precisely do you mean by not yet published? Previewing draft post?

Comment: Yes, sorry. That's what I mean!

Comment: @Rarst edited for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`is_preview()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_preview) is supported. You may also want to look into [`is_singular()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) which covers posts, pages, and attachments.